# Multiple subdomains with django

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, httpd.conf

I'm trying to run two applications on a webserver with Django + Apache at `signal.server.com` and `noise.server.com`.

Currently both URLs point to `singal.server.com`

I've been changing options around to no avail. Here is my virtual host for the server.com which works fine

```bsh
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/d_signal
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin hello@mail.server.com
        ServerName www.server.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/server.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

virtual config for singal.server.com

```bsh
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hello@server.com
    ServerName signal.server.com
    ServerAlias signal.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/d_signal/d_signal
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/d_signal/d_signal/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess signal.server.com python-home=/var/www/html/d_signal/signal_env socket-user=apache
    WSGIProcessGroup signal.server.com

     Alias /static /var/www/html/d_signal/static
     <Directory /var/www/html/d_signal/sig/templates/sig/static>
         #Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <Directory /var/www/html/d_signal/d_signal>
    AllowOverride all 
    #Require all granted 
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
         <Files wsgi.py>
             #Require all granted
         </Files>
     </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

And the virtual config for noise.server.com

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hello@server.com
    ServerName noise.server.com
    ServerAlias noise.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/d_signal/noise
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/d_signal/d_signal/wsgi_noise.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess noise.server.com python-home=/var/www/html/d_signal/noise_env socket-user=apache
    WSGIProcessGroup noise.server.com

     Alias /static /var/www/html/d_signal/static
     <Directory /var/www/html/d_signal/sig/templates/sig/static>
         #Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <Directory /var/www/html/d_signal/noise>
    AllowOverride all 
    #Require all granted 
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
         <Files wsgi_noise.py>
             #Require all granted
         </Files>
     </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

If I visit `http://noise.server.com/noise/` then I get to the app I want to see but I'd rather just have `http://noise.server.com` work.

My config is one Django project with two apps.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "then I get to the app I want to see". What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @dirkgroten I'd rather not have to add the path.

Comment: are those separate django projects with their own url config? Or are we talking about one django project with two apps?

Comment: This is one Django project with two apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration is correct. Turns out my issue was in my settings file which was still pointing the noise.server.com to the main app.

Double check your settings files.